# Assert keyword in Groovy Language

Tags: groovy

I am beginner for groovy language. Why we are using assert keyword in groovy language? When I am learning groovy language, I saw that keyword asset used often. Is it mandatory to use assert keyword every time when we define a variable. plz explain in detail

Comment: [assert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)) is not specific to just groovy.

Comment: It's just a good way of documenting examples. By using the `assert` statement you can show what an example's expected output is as part of the example, while keeping the example valid code.

Comment: "Is it mandatory to use assert keyword every time when we define a variable" - Definitely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_power_assertion

it's not necessary to use assert.

Assert just verifies the value or condition. if condition falsy assert will throw exception with details.

Compare `assert b==2` with  almost identical code:

```
if( !(b==2) ) throw new Exception("$b not equals to 2")
```

try following code to understand how it works

```
def b=1
assert b==1  //just verifies that b equals to 1
assert b==2  //throws exception with details why b not equals to 2
```

You could use `println(b)` instead of `assert b==2` and verify condition/value by your eyes...